# How to clone an mat array by pointer c++

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I new in opencv, and I have a program where IplImage is used but I want to update to Mat, so there are things where I don't know exactly how to modify the program, for example this line :

```
 void setDataToWork(Mat* sources)/* Before it was IplImage* sources*/
   {
        src = sources ;
        ...
        ...
     {
        /*segm = cvCloneImage( sources ) ;*/ 
        /*ch_h = cvCloneImage( segMsk )*/;          
         sources->clone();
     }

  }
```

I need to clone the sources and ch_h, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace all occurrences of `IplImage` to `cv::Mat` because the API has been totally changed, some methods does not exist, some has been renamed, etc.
The only thing you can do is to create a wrapper `cv::Mat` object to your old `IplImage` by the constructor below

```
cv::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);
```

In practice:

```
IplImage* iplImage = ...

cv::Mat matFromIpl(iplImage);

// use matFromIpl from here
```